# Fix sql injection

Tags: python, postgresql

I try to rebuild this function

```
def getStackArea(screen_area):
    db = postgresql.open(db_conf.connectionString())
    data = db.query("select stack_area from screen_coordinates where screen_area = " + screen_area + " and active = 1")
    return data[0]['stack_area']
```

To

```
def getStackArea(screen_area):
    db = postgresql.open(db_conf.connectionString())
    sql = "select stack_area from screen_coordinates where screen_area = ? and active = ?"
    row = db.query.first(sql, (screen_area,1))
    return data[0]['stack_area']
```

But there is `syntax error at or near "and"`. What I do wrong? First function works good but not safety. I use py-postgresql

Comment: What library are you using? That will affect what characters will be treated as placeholders. The error message you give implies the `? as being passed literally to the SQL engine, rather than be replaced first by the given arguments.

Comment: @chepner I use py-postgresql

Comment: The example on https://pypi.org/project/py-postgresql/ suggests `sql = "select ... where screen_area = $1 and active = $2"` instead.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. It works. If post the answer I vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`py-postgresql` uses numbered parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc, rather than `?` as placeholders.

```
sql = "select stack_area from screen_coordinates where screen_area = $1 and active = $2"
```